# How to set the app controls for landscape mode or portrait mode?

Tags: ios, uiview, landscape

I know Auto Layout can be used to make the sizes and position consistent when the orientation changes. Is it possible to completely change the layout when the orientation changes? Means when the device is rotated to landscape mode all the controllers can be changed their position and set accordingly the device mode . And this could be done for all the devices of iPhone 4,5,6 ,6 plus.Without using storyboard. Anybody can help me out for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

****for view to superview
[self addEdgeConstraint:NSLayoutAttributeLeft superview:self.view subview:subView];

```
[self addEdgeConstraint:NSLayoutAttributeRight superview:self.view subview:subView];

[self addEdgeConstraint:NSLayoutAttributeTop superview:self.view subview:subView];

[self addEdgeConstraint:NSLayoutAttributeBottom superview:self.view subview:subView];
```

-(void)addEdgeConstraint:(NSLayoutAttribute)edge superview:(NSView *)superview subview:(NSView *)subview

{
    [superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:edge relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                 toItem:superview   attribute:edge multiplier:1 constant:0]];

}

for vertical spacing between views

NSMutableArray* newVerticalConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];

```
[newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[view1]” options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewMainBanner)]];

[newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view1]-%d-[view2]”,10] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2)]];

[newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view2]-%d-[view3]”,10]  options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view2, view3)]];

[newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view3]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view3)]];

[self.view addConstraints:newVerticalConstraints];***
```

///instead of v we can use 'H' for horizontal spacing

Comment: Can u explain more your answer. I can't get you

Comment: if you need space between left part of the view and its super view use the        [self addEdgeConstraint:NSLayoutAttributeLeft superview:self.view subview:subView];

Comment: for vertical spce between two view NSMutableArray* newVerticalConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];           [newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view1]-%d-[view2]”,10] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2)]];                                       [self.view addConstraints:newVerticalConstraints];

Comment: This code does not work for vertical space.Your above code of addEdge Works Correctly.. Can u plz correct this again

Comment: NSMutableArray* newVerticalConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];                         [newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[view1]” options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1)]];    [newVerticalConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view1]-%d-[view2]”,10] options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2)]]; [self.view addConstraints:newVerticalConstraints];  view1 and view2 are your subviews objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90433/discussion-between-shebin-and-nisha-gupta).